# accessing methods in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Consider the following Java script code:

```
    var myObj = function (  ) {
        var x = 0;
        return {
            addup: function (y) {
                x += y;
            },
            getX: function (  ) {
                return x;
            }
        }
    }();
```

This function returns an object with two methods (if I am not wrong).

now, two questions:

1. how can I call the two methods returned  from the function?
2. can those methods still have access to the variable x ?

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `myObj.getX();` and `myObj.addup(5);`
2. Yes, they still have access

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/qWT9N/

Answer (score 2):

how can I call the two methods returned from the function?

```
myObj.addup(10);
var xValue = myObj.getX();
```

can those methods still have access to the variable x ? **Yes**

Comment: addup doesn't return anything.

Answer (score -1):

You've created "template" object `myObj` with private `x` propery and two public methods.

To create object based on your "template" call `var obj = myObj();`

1. You can call them like `obj.addup(2);` and `obj.getX();`
2. Yes those methods have access to Private `x` variable from them